# Error passing data between table view controller to detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting an error while passing data from a table view controller to a detail view
 controller.  I am using a navigation controller along with it.

The error message is as follows:

> use of undeclared identifier _wordLabel

This is the prepare for segue implementation in my table view controller (.m file).

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowWordDetails"]) {

        //UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        wordDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];
        detailViewController.wordDetailModel = @[_wordLabel[row], _meaningLabel[row]];
    }
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

I have previously declared `wordLabel` and `meaningLabel` in the detail view controller as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *meaningLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *wordDetailModel;
```

I have also declared it in `viewDidLoad` method of detail view controller as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _wordLabel.text = _wordDetailModel[0];
    _meaningLabel.text = _wordDetailModel[1];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_wordLabel` is private member of your detailViewController. You can't access it like you're trying to do in the first code quote. You need to call `detailViewController.wordLabel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can't use the array operator with a UILabel

```
_wordLabel[row]
```

second of all you have to define the _wordLabel[row] as an array in the TVC, that is separate from the label in the detailViewController

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't require `wordDetailModel` as you can access `UILabel` from `TableViewController` as described below

```
detailViewController.wordLabel.text = @"Word";
detailViewController.meaningLabel.text = @"Meaning";
```

`_wordLabel` is `UILabel` and it is private variable in `DetailViewController` which can not be used directly from `TableViewController`, you have to use it using `property`. Plus `_wordLabel` is not an array as already answered by @sha and @rockstarr